# How do you enable monitoring data for MobileFirst on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I've got the MobileFirst starter container running on Bluemix. For some reason, I have no data for CPU, memory, or network traffic. How do I enable this data?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tab on bluemix that allow you to have simple data monitoring, the second and better choice is to provide a SSH key when you create your container and access it via SSH and use standard linux metics or install your tool of choice.

I like to use "top", simple and complete.

To access a container via SSH you can do like this:

```
ssh  -i ./id_rsa root@<continer ip>
```

where "-i" enable you point to a file with a key to allow you to connect to it.

Comment: What tab do you mean? When I look at my Container... and crap - now it shows up. I have no idea why for the past few days it had no data, and now magically it does.

Comment: I want to add though - what tab do you mean? I don't see one here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOLYOtPospAMKkddenP3jkJVw1x0Mq1vaI

Comment: On this screen you have just 2 working choices: Memory(Disk) and CPU. You can change by pressing on the "gear" button  at the top right of the white box.

Comment: For more monitoring, I would connect directly on the container via SSH and use Linux tools.

Comment: Ok, but do you know why monitoring was blank for days?

Answer (score 0):

IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 capabilities are now available on Bluemix as a service called Mobile Foundation.The  Mobile foundation 8.0 service on bluemix now allows you to integrate the analytics which gives you the data for CPU, memory, or network traffic, mobile app usage etc.

Users can create Analytics server on containers to integrate with the MobileFirstServer on Liberty Build Pack.

Note : Mobile Foundation service in Sydney does not have Analytics as of now due to lack of container service in Sydney.